# How to get all terms's parent data in PnP?

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp, term

I'm updating the dependencies of an old project, and one of them is upgrading from `PnP 1.x` to `3.x`. We'll be running it on the latest `SharePoint Online`.

In old project, it write the code to retrieve a term like this:

```typescript
import { sp } from "@pnp/sp";
import { Session, ITermStore } from "@pnp/sp-taxonomy";

    const taxonomy = new Session(this.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl);
    const store: ITermStore = taxonomy.termStores.getById(termStoreName);
    return store.groups
      .getById(groupName)
      .termSets.getByName(termsetName)
      .terms.select(
       // select ...
      )
      .get()
      .then((data) => {
        // more code...
      })
```

In the old website, the request speed was somewhat satisfactory and acceptable

While going through the relevant documentation, I discovered that my colleague used a higher-cost request [getAllChildrenAsOrderedTree](https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/sp/taxonomy/#getallchildrenasorderedtree)

```typescript
import '@pnp/sp/webs'
import '@pnp/sp/lists'
import '@pnp/sp/items'
import '@pnp/sp/taxonomy'
import { IOrderedTermInfo, ITermInfo } from '@pnp/sp/taxonomy'

this.sp.termStore.groups
        .getById(groupName)
        .sets.getById(termSetName)
        .getAllChildrenAsOrderedTree({ retrieveProperties: true })
        .then((res) => {
            // more code ...
        })
```

Indeed, as stated in the documentation, this request is known to have the longest execution time.

That's quite critical for this website because, due to the requirements, I cannot implement code-level caching for the speed of the post-request as suggested in the documentation.

And then I tried using other APIs from the documentation to fetch additional parameters：

```typescript
 this.sp.termStore.groups
      .getById(this.resourceData['term-group'])
      .sets.getById(this.resourceData['term-name'])
      .terms.select(...['*', 'localProperties'])
      .then((res) => {
         // Todo...
      })
```

The above code allows me to retrieve the data of all child nodes of the SPFx term, but I can't find the connection between them and their parent nodes

But I don't want to query the parent node data for each term using getParent like in the [documentation](https://pnp.github.io/pnpjs/sp/taxonomy/#get-term-parent).

This approach can potentially impose a similar request burden and performance impact as the previous getAllChildrenAsOrderedTree method.

So, is there any solution to address this issue? If it can't be resolved in `PnP 3.x`, I might need to pause the upgrade plan for this particular functionality

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I specifically raised an [issue](https://github.com/pnp/pnpjs/issues/2761) in pnp/js to resolve the problem, and it seems that the maintainer's response is suggesting me to use the native interface to solve the issue.

Firstly, using the older version of `pnp`, you can immediately retrieve the corresponding content, and the difference with `v3` is that it allows accessing the `Parent` field.

The tricky part is that you need to construct an `XML request payload`, and for that, you can refer to the request headers of `pnp v1` / the native request.

The xml request seem like:

```xml
    <Request
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/clientquery/2009"
        SchemaVersion="15.0.0.0"
        LibraryVersion="16.0.0.0"
        ApplicationName="PnPjs"
      >
          <Actions>
              <ObjectPath Id="1" ObjectPathId="0" />
              <ObjectPath
                  Id="3"
                  ObjectPathId="2" />
              <ObjectPath Id="5" ObjectPathId="4" />
              <ObjectPath
                  Id="8"
                  ObjectPathId="7" />
              <ObjectPath Id="11" ObjectPathId="10" />
              <ObjectPath
                  Id="13"
                  ObjectPathId="12" />
              <Query Id="14" ObjectPathId="12"
              >
                  <Query SelectAllProperties="true">
                      <Properties />
                  </Query>
                  <ChildItemQuery SelectAllProperties="false"
                  >
                      <Properties>
                          <Property Name="Name" SelectAll="true" />
                          <Property
                              Name="Id"
                              SelectAll="true" />
                          <Property
                              Name="Description"
                              SelectAll="true" />
                          <Property
                              Name="Parent"
                              SelectAll="true" />
                          <Property
                              Name="LocalCustomProperties"
                              SelectAll="true" />
                          <Property
                              Name="TermsCount"
                              SelectAll="true" />
                          <Property
                              Name="PathOfTerm"
                              SelectAll="true" />
                          <Property
                              Name="CustomSortOrder"
                              SelectAll="true" />
                      </Properties>
                  </ChildItemQuery>
              </Query>
          </Actions>
          <ObjectPaths>
              <StaticMethod
                  Id="0"
                  Name="GetTaxonomySession"
                  TypeId="{some id ...}" />
              <Property
                  Id="2"
                  ParentId="0"
                  Name="TermStores" />
              <Method Id="4" ParentId="2" Name="GetById"
              >
                  <Parameters>
                      <Parameter Type="String"
                      >${this.resourceData['term-store-name']}</Parameter>
                  </Parameters>
              </Method>
              <Property Id="6" ParentId="4" Name="Groups" />
              <Method
                  Id="7"
                  ParentId="6"
                  Name="GetById"
              >
                  <Parameters>
                      <Parameter Type="String"
                      >${this.resourceData['term-group']}</Parameter>
                  </Parameters>
              </Method>
              <Property Id="9" ParentId="7" Name="TermSets" />
              <Method
                  Id="10"
                  ParentId="9"
                  Name="GetById"
              >
                  <Parameters>
                      <Parameter Type="String">${this.resourceData['term-name']}</Parameter>
                  </Parameters>
              </Method>
              <Method Id="12" ParentId="10" Name="GetAllTerms"></Method>
          </ObjectPaths>
      </Request>
```

And then you can proceed with making the API request. Here is my implementation (which might be a bit cumbersome):

```js
import { SPHttpClient } from '@microsoft/sp-http'
// I use it in Spfx extension, if webpart is WebpartContext
import { ApplicationCustomizerContext } from '@microsoft/sp-application-base'

 const requestHeader = new Headers()
      requestHeader.append('Content-type', 'text/xml;charset=utf-8')
      const csoXml = '...'
this.context.spHttpClient
        .post(
          `${this.context.pageContext.site.absoluteUrl}/_vti_bin/client.svc/ProcessQuery`,
          SPHttpClient.configurations.v1,
          {
            headers: requestHeader,
            body: csoXml
          }
        )
        .then((response) => {
          if (response.ok) {
            response
              .json()
              .then((res) => {
                console.log('Test:', res)
                const result = this.handlerTermData(res)
                debugger
                resolve(res)
              })
              .catch((err) => {
                reject(err)
              })
          }
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          reject(err)
        })
```

Please note that the data structure obtained from the `native API` request is somewhat peculiar (I can't find another word to describe it).

The actual data resides in the last item of the returned array, which is a `Term` Data object with accompanying parent node information.

You will need to process it separately to reconstruct the `tree-like` structure.